# How to create new Python Turtle image each iteration?

Tags: python, drawing, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to create 100 images via Python Turtle and **each iteration there should be **only 2 geometric shapes**** drawn on each image (files test0.jpg, test1.jpg etc). However, in my code each next image is drawn on the previous one, which causes collision. Can you help me please?

```
import turtle
import random
from PIL import Image


def generate(tur1):
    a = random.randint(2, 7)
    b = random.randint(2, 7)
    c = random.randint(50, 100)
    if a != 2:
        for i in range(a):
            tur1.forward(c)
            tur1.left(360.0 / a)
    else:
        tur1.circle(c)

    tur1.penup()
    tur1.goto(-200, 0)
    tur1.pendown()

    if b != 2:
        for j in range(b):
            tur1.forward(c)
            tur1.left(360.0 / b)
    else:
        tur1.circle(c)


for i in range(0, 100):
    tur2 = turtle.Turtle()
    tur2.color('green')
    tur2.speed(1)
    tur2.hideturtle()
    generate(tur2)
    screen = tur2.getscreen()
    screen.setup(600, 600)
    canvas = screen.getcanvas()
    canvas.postscript(file="test"+str(i)+".eps")
    img = Image.open("test"+str(i)+".eps")
    img.save("test"+str(i)+".jpg")
```

Comment: [`turtle.clear()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.clear)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like `turtle.clear()` (+1 @JohnnyMopp) or more likely `turtle.reset()`, or `turtle.home()` in combination with `turtle.clear()`, since you moved the turtle.  A slight rework of your code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint
from PIL import Image

def generate(turtle):
    a = randint(2, 7)
    b = randint(50, 100)

    if a == 2:
        turtle.circle(b)
    else:
        for _ in range(a):
            turtle.forward(b)
            turtle.left(360 / a)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(-200)
    turtle.pendown()

    a = randint(2, 7)

    if a == 2:
        turtle.circle(b)
    else:
        for _ in range(a):
            turtle.forward(b)
            turtle.left(360 / a)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)

turtle = Turtle()

for i in range(10):
    # inside loop only because reset() also resets these...
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.color('green')
    turtle.speed('fastest')

    eps = "test" + str(i) + ".eps"
    jpg = "test" + str(i) + ".jpg"

    generate(turtle)
    canvas = screen.getcanvas()

    canvas.postscript(file=eps)
    img = Image.open(eps)
    img.save(jpg)

    turtle.reset()
```